# Self-similarity of a dendrite fractal

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

The Julia set of the map $z \mapsto z^2+i$ is a dendrite fractal.  I would like to know which <del>affine</del> maps (other than identity) map this region to a subset of itself.  I imagine there are <del>two</del> three generators, but maybe there are more.  Perhaps I am after an "iterated function system" which will generate the dendrite fractal (possibly as the limit of trees).

[image] [<sup>(source: Wikipedia)</sup>](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Dendrite_julia.png/783px-Dendrite_julia.png)

Comment: Some comments:

1. I'm fairly sure there are no such affine maps, although proving it rigorously could be hard. Proving that there are no similarities might be easier using ideas of Andras Mathe and others.

2. The Julia set is invariant under the iterated function system given by the inverse branches of z^2+i, which are of course non linear. 

3. Some dendrite Julia sets are conjugated to self-similar (i.e. linear) dendrites. Eroglu, Rohde and Solomyak proved that in some cases the conjugacy is quasi-symmetric.

Maybe you can clarify what you need to know and what is the motivation?

Comment: I'm quite sure $z\mapsto -z$ is such an affine map.

Comment: @Ricky.  Yeah.  Maybe I should have said "maps to a proper subset of itself".

Comment: @Pablo.  I was looking for a the combinatorial structure of this fractal.  Maybe this dendrite arises as the scaling limit of a sequence of trees embedded in $\mathbb{C}$? Something promising appeared in paper by Nekrasyevich, but I couldn't quite decipher it. 

Comment: @Pablo: Linear dendrite fractals might do.  Was just wondering about continuous functions on these sets.  

Comment: Some fractals arise as limit sets of "iterated function systems" of affine maps (like the Gosper snowflake).  In this case, the maps are non-linear.  My mistake.

Comment: Assume that there exists at least two contracting affine maps A1, A2,... that maps the dendrite into itself. Then, each possible sequence of compositions of such maps also has this property.

Hence, a subset of the dendrite can be generated by a Hutchinson operator
with affine generators. One can think of this set as the set of fixed points of
all compositions of the generators.

That the dendrite can be generated in such fashion seem just "wrong";
that kind of pattern does not emerge from affine Hutchinson operators.


Comment: @John, Nekrashevych's work is not the easiest to read but it is worthwhile if you are looking for combinatorial properties since it will give you an associated group action that may show those properties more clearly. 

Comment: +1 for the question, though along with Pablo, I think the emphasis on _affine_ maps is wrong.  I made a conjecture about combinatorial decompositions of Julia sets, along the same lines: Conjecture 2.11 of  http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4474.  (For the general gist, see p.13-14.)

Comment: The maps here are not affine.   But they are conformal.  The set can be divided into a finite number of parts (maybe 2 or 4), so that each part is the image of 2 of the parts under a conformal map.  In fact, the conformal maps are branches of the inverse of $z^2+i$, namely $\pm \sqrt{w-i}$.   A student of mine, Jeff Golds, worked out some cases, but for certain Julia sets that are homeomorphically circles.

Comment: Gerald, are you talking about section 4 of math.osu.edu/~edgar/preprints/golds/edgar992.pdf?  And is there further work?  

Comment: @Tom: yes, that's it. No further work ... Jeff defected to "the dark side" (computer programming) :)   ... Well, actually further work (by other mathematicians) using the thermodynamic formalism seems to be the way to advance this.

Answer (score 5):

What you are after is really the combinatorics of the branched cover $z\mapsto z^2+i$ on the Julia set $J$. Namely, you really want to consider $J$ as a *dynamical system*, and not just as a topological space.
As mentioned above, the map $z\mapsto z^2+i$ is not linear, but you could approximate it by something piecewise linear if you want: you would then get an equivalent dynamical system on the corresponding Julia set.

As a mere topological space, the set of homeomorphisms of $J$ is *HUGE*.
The space $J$ is actually uniquely characterized up to homeomorphism by the following properties:

- it is compact metrizable.
- it is one dimensional.
- it is locally connected and simply connected.
- all its points have valence 1, 2, or 3
  (here, the *valence* is the number of connected components that you get after removing the point)
- the set of points of valence 3 is dense.

This is a little bit similar to the characterization of the Cantor set as the unique compact metrizable zero-dimensional space with no isolated points.
So you see that you have a lot of freedom, and that you can represent many, many dynamical systems on that same topological space $J$.

Comment: André, can you give us a reference for this unique characterization of J?  Thanks.  

Comment: No. I just made it up. But I also have a kind-of-vague-argument in my head that  proves that any two spaces with those properties are indeed homeomorphic.

Comment: OK!  Well, if you ever see an argument like this in print, or write one yourself, I'd be interested to hear about it.  (I know the characterization of the Cantor set that you mention, but this is more sophisticated.)

Comment: I forgot to impose a local connectivity condition...

Comment: $J$ has the topological type of a compact $\mathbb{R}$-tree whose singular points have valence 3 or 1, such that the valence 3 points form a countably infinite dense subset.  Given two such spaces, one can construct a homeomorphism by specifying a correspondence on the countable sets of valence 3 points, and such a correspondence can be chosen recursively using the geodesic structure.


Answer (score 4):

OK, as hinted in my comment.  Here is the fractal $J$:

[image: J1]

Now choose a branch of the squareroot so that $\sqrt{w-i}$ is continuous on this set.  Here is the image of $J$ under the map  $\sqrt{w-i}$ in green, and the image of $J$ under the map $-\sqrt{w-i}$ in red:

[image: J2]

Thus $J$ is the attractor of a certain IFS (but not using affine maps).

Comment: The set could be called *self-conformal* not *self-similar*.

Comment: Some examples of this kind were studied in: 
Barnsley, M. F.; Demko, S. Iterated function systems and the global construction of fractals.  Proc. Roy. Soc. London Ser. A  399  (1985),  no. 1817, 243–275